# Randomly generating an array of unique chars. Know of better ways to do it now, but wondering why my original method doesn't work

Tags: java, logic

I am supposed to be generating a randomly ordered alphabet. I know of shuffle methods and things like the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm, but what I originally tried to do would never work. I had a "reference" array of the alphabet in regular order. I would then have a for loop for each 26 spaces. I would generate a random int between 0 and 25(for the index in the reference array). Then, I would check if the array already has that char in it(it must be unique) If it is unique, I add it to the array. It still has duplicates though. Here's my code:

```
public static final char[] ALPHABET = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
                                      'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                                      'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' '};
public static char[]    cipherGenerator(){
    char[] cipherAlpha = new char[26];
    for(int index = 0; index < 26; index++){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int newLetter = rand.nextInt(25);
        char newChar = ALPHABET[newLetter];

        while(Arrays.asList(cipherAlpha).contains(newChar)){
            newLetter = rand.nextInt(25);
            newChar = ALPHABET[newLetter];
        }
        cipherAlpha[index] = newChar;

    }
    return cipherAlpha;
}
```

This returns code with duplicates, despite me trying everything to try and find the logic error. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an primitive array such as `char[]` to `Arrays.asList`, that method can't return a `List<char>`, because primitive types aren't allowed as type arguments.  But it can and does produce a `List<char[]>`.  Your random `char` is never equal to the single `char[]` inside the `List`, so any duplicate `char` is allowed.  If you use a `Character[]` instead of the `char[]` for `cipherAlpha`, and change the return type of the method to `Character[]`, then `Arrays.asList` will infer the type argument `Character` correctly, allowing for your duplicate check to work correctly.

Second, `nextInt(25)` will generate a random index between `0` and `24`, not `25`.  You can use `ALPHABET.length`, which is 26 here.  With the first change but without this change, you will only have 25 distinct characters, and you will never find a 26th distinct character, looping forever.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question, and not suggesting another algorithm. The questioner clearly states that he understands his algorithm is not optimal, but is wondering why it isn't working at all.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I never would've figured that one out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Add you Alphabet in a ArrayList and remove the element selected at each turn of your while. Then update your rand.nextInt like:

```
rand.nextInt(AlphabetList.size());
```

And your ALPHABET like:

```
List<char> AlphabetList = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the Random numbers generated are duplicate, To overcome this you can keep on adding numbers to the Collection Set till you have all unique numbers

```
    while(set.size()< 26) {
        while (set.add(random.nextInt(26)) != true);
    }
```

Other way is add all integer to the list & then shuffle it.

```
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        numberList.add(new Integer(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

You can directly do shuffle on the characters if you wish.

```
List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
Collections.shuffle(characters);
```